# jcarousel displaying items in vertical list before jquery page

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, jcarousel

I'm using the jquery plugin jcarousel to display 73 thumbnails. Before the script is ready, it shows all the thumbnails in a vertical list down the page. At the moment, I am using a script to show the images at the correct size once everything is loaded.

Just wondering if I would be able to get opinions on whether this is a good approach and if there are better ways to hide content until the jquery is fully loaded? :)

The code:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
 jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: <?=$page?>
});
});
```

dynamic CSS

```
 $(window).load(function() {
 $(".jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item img").css({height: "125px", width: "125px"});
 });
```

html image

```
 <img src="images/img.jpg" height="0">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a good reason to initialize the carousel with window load. Apart from that, I would work with `visibility:hidden`. The plugin can work with the images real sizes and it's hidden.

HTML

```
<img src="images/img.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

Then, it's better to make the images visible on the plugin's callback:

jQuery

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        start: <?=$page?>,
        initCallback:function(){
            jQuery(".jcarousel-item img").css({'visibility':'visible'});
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.